# Kotlin getting api response with foreach

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So, what I'm trying to do is to get information from api and add it to model: MutableList and then set model information to recycler view. But the problem is, recycler view is being called before api gets all responses and so, my view is empty. This is what i concluded, if I'm wrong please correct me. But if not, How can I fix this problem?

```
class FavouritesFragment(myContext : HomeActivity, fvts: ArrayList<String>): Fragment() {
    var activity = myContext
    var favourites = fvts
    var model : MutableList<CurrentWeatherModel> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourites, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        model.clear()
        favourites.forEach {
            getForecastModel(it)}

        Log.d("other", model.size.toString())
        favouritesRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        val adapter = CurrentRecyclerViewAdapter(model, activity)
        favouritesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    private fun getForecastModel(value: String?) {
        if (!value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            DataLoader.getRequestForQuery("weather", value, "a77840cefd5a443793bd5e6b54776905", object: CustomCallback{
                override fun onSuccess(result: String) {
                    if (result != "null") {
                        var converted = Gson().fromJson(result, CurrentWeatherModel::class.java)
                        model.add(converted)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to notify the adapter that data has changed, you can achieve this by calling  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever the data has changed.

So you need to add this line after adding data to the list

```
model.add(converted)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```